# Получить видео с вк

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую метод wall.getById. Получаю ответ, в котором помимо прочего есть

```
{"type":"video","video":{"vid": ну и т.д.
```

Можно ли получить код плеера к примеру по vid ? Про video.get в курсе, но там заморочка с

```
Для вызова этого метода Ваше приложение должно иметь права: video.
```

Comment: И что мешает получить права `video`?

Comment: Мне просто лень регистрироваться в вк, учитывая что там еще и номер телефона требуют, поэтому и спросил можно ли как-то без регистрации это сделать, к примеру тот же wall.get работает без всяких регистраций

Comment: А мне лень зачитывать вам  вслух документацию.

Comment: Спасибо, я ее читал, вопрос был в том можно ли получить к примеру код плеера  по vid

Answer (score 2):

Создайте приложение ВК (http://vk.com/dev) и при авторизации добавьте `video` в параметр `scope`.